# What is the equivalent of coo_matrix in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to translatethe following lines of code from Python to MATLAB. `V`, `Id`, and `J` are of size `(6400,)` which in MATLAB are 1 *-by-* 6400 row vectors. `pts` is of size 242.

My Python code

```py
A = coo_matrix((V, (Id, J)), shape=(pts.size, pts.size)).tocsr()
A = A.tobsr(blocksize=(2, 2))
```

I translated the first line as follows to MATLAB

```matlab
A = sparse(V,Id,J,242,242);
```

However, I got the error

```matlab
Error using sparse
Index into matrix must be an integer.
```

How can I translate this code to MATLAB?

Comment: I assume you tried S = sparse(i,j,v). When you say it didn't work can you add to your question what happened and what you expected?

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question and added the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function has several forms:

```
S = sparse(A)
S = sparse(m,n)
S = sparse(i,j,v)
S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n)
S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n,nz)
```

The form you are most likely looking for is the fourth one: `S = sparse(i,j,v,m,n)`, and will want to call it (using your use case) as:

```
A = sparse(Id, J, V, 242, 242);
```

I think your error is that MATLAB wants the I and J indices first, followed by the value and you are making the value the first argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I get the Error using sparse
Index exceeds array bounds. This is weird cause it's supposed to be a space matrix so technically it should not exceed it.

Comment: Try with just the first three arguments and see what you end up with. I don’t have access to matlab at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. No Error, but the size of A is 218*245. But according to python output, A should be 242 * 242. All the matrices are the same I wonder why I face such errors.